# Generating all possible permutations for a given length and set of characters

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert this Python function, which uses the `itertools` library, to VB.Net:

```py
permutations = itertools.product('ab', repeat=3)
```

The above function returns all permutations:

```py
[['a','a','a'],
 ['a','a','b'],
 ['a','b','a'],
 ['a','b','b'],
 ['b','a','a'],
 ['b','a','b'],
 ['b','b','a'],
 ['b','b','b']]
```

Is there a nice clean way to do this in VB.Net?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question, if I'm not mistaken.  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21090635/2319909

Comment: i'm looking for some sort of library or one liner native function or may be linq.. something simple

Comment: OK... This will do it though.. Permutation.Create({"a"c, "b"c, "c"c}, sort:=True) not sweet enough for you?

Comment: Add the class that dude provided, then reference it.

Comment: it doesn't have option for string length

Comment: @SamMakin +1 for referencing instead of c&p without attribution:)

Comment: Can you clarify what the repeat paramter does?  I'm still not sure looking at the documentation.

Comment: like say i have 'a' and 'b' and i want to permute them like 'aaaab' 'abaaa'... etc where the output length is 5 here

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the python `itertools.product` function to vb.net:

```
Function Permute (chars As List (Of Char), len As Integer) As List (Of List (Of Char))
    Dim pools As New List (Of List (Of Char))
    Dim result As New List (Of List (Of Char)) From {New List (Of Char)}
    For i = 0 To len - 1
        pools.Add (chars)
    Next
    For Each pool As List (Of Char) In pools
        Dim result2 As New List (Of List (Of Char))
        For Each x In result
            For Each y In pool
                Dim temp As New List (Of Char)(x)
                temp.Add (y)
                result2.Add (temp)
            Next
        Next
        result = New List (Of List (Of Char))(result2)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```